# Download a file with javascript without any prompt name select, path select window

Tags: javascript, html, docker, svg, download

I'm generating pdf files from a html file using decktape (and ofc reveal.js) inside a docker image. In the html file there are multiple svg files, which i need to download separately.

My idea was to create a script which automatically downloads the svg-s with the computed css when the html file is opened. But I have to solve the problem of the prompt window. Is there any way to download files automatically with javascript without the prompt window popping up?

I'm already able to download the file with the prompt window popping up, but I would like to do it without that, automatically. This is happening on a Linux Debian 9 server, and the decktape is using a Chromium.

Comment: wouldn't a way to download random malicious stuff onto your device be just lovely for bad actors. Browsers are always going to leave users rather than sites in control here.